# WTForm does not entirely repopulate form data upon editing a model

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, peewee

> Edit: Category field is now able to repopulate. Made a mistake in
>   retrieving the data. App.py has been edited.

I recently created an "edit post" form in which the user clicks on a link, and a few parameters are sent to a function. My function searches for the post and the wtform module attempts to repopulate the form with the data from the post targeted. It seems  that the **url** (URLField), **category** (SelectField) and **name** (StringField) are able to repopulate, but the  **details** (TextField) fields display a value of None. Can anyone guide me towards to right direction in terms of repopulating a flask-wtform?

Here was my attempt:

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/edit_post/<int:post_id>', methods=("GET","POST"))
@login_required
def edit_my_post(post_id):
    posts = models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id)
    if posts.count() == 0:
        abort(404)


    if post_user.id == current_user.id :
        post = models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id).get()
        form = forms.ProductForm(obj=post)

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            form.populate_obj(post)
            query = models.Post.update(user = post.user.id,
                               name = form.name.data.strip(),
                               content = form.details.data.strip(),
                               url = form.url.data,
                               category = = form.category.data
                              ).where(models.Post.id == post_id)
            query.execute()
            flash("Your post has been edited.", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        flash("Ay! Stay away from that post!","warning")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template("edit.html",form=form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model = User,
        related_name = 'posts'
    )
    name = TextField()
    content = TextField()
    upvotes = IntegerField(default=0)
    url = TextField()
    category = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Content Name', validators = [DataRequired()])
    url = URLField(validators=[url()])
    details = TextAreaField('Content Summary', validators = [DataRequired(),Length(max=140)])
    category = SelectField("Choose a category that your content fits in.", choices=CATEGORIES,coerce=int)
```

**edit.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% from 'macros.html' import render_field %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {% for field in form %}
    {{ render_field(field) }}
  {% endfor %}
  <br>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Edit Post</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

> Note: CATEGORIES is a (long) array of strings.

Comment: You should post your template form code too.

Comment: I implemented the template code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed the issue by simply renaming the details ProductForm field to the same name as the property on the Post form. So now the form code looks like this:

```
class ProductForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Content Name', validators = [DataRequired()])
    url = URLField(validators=[url()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content Summary', validators = [DataRequired(),Length(max=140)])
    category = SelectField("Choose a category that your content fits in.", choices=CATEGORIES,coerce=int)
```

And I renamed parts of the query to retrieve the data like so:

```
query = models.Post.update(user = post.user.id,
                               name = form.name.data.strip(),
                               content = form.content.data.strip(),
                               url = form.url.data,
                               category = form.category.data
                              ).where(models.Post.id == post_id)
            query.execute()
```